# Why can't I find visual studio generators in cmake?

Tags: build, visual-studio-2017, cmake, generator

I am trying to install clang by creating a .sln file using cmake.
To generate the file I used this command inside the build directory:

```
cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A x64 -Thost=x64 ..\clang
```

But I am getting an error that there are no generators with name "Visual Studio 15 2017".
Output of the command:

```
CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 15 2017

Generators
  Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Watcom WMake                 = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
```

System information:
The system is: Linux - 4.15.0-43-generic - x86_64
cmake version: 3.12.2

Comment: Are you running CMake on non-Windows OS?

Comment: yes @arrowd, on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Well, that's why you don't see VS generators.

Comment: So there aren't generators for the linux version of VS? And if not then how can I create a .sln file to load into VS?